# Why do I get "Cannot resolve method scheduleAtFixedRate"?

Tags: android, class, timertask

I have no idea to why I am recieving this error. With all the example I've seen with the class `TimerTask` , this should not cause a problem.

```
public class CountUp extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText upText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Up);
int counter = 0;
float StartTime = 0;
float OffsetTime = 1000;    //Offset time is the time between event. 1000 is going to be our milliseconds (1 second)

TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        upText.setText(counter);
        counter++;
    }
};

public void CountUp(View view){
    try {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt,StartTime,OffsetTime); <--- //This is were I am receiving an error
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your onCreate method? You are writing all code instantly. That's totally wrong.

Comment: @HusseinElFeky I didn't include my onCreate method cause that's not the one that I am getting an error from. I didn't want to include to much code that doesn't have with the problem to do.

Comment: Well, did you try my answer below? You had three mistakes. First of all, startTime and offsetTime must be long and not float. Second, you should declare tt above onCreate as you reference it from another method. Third, you must setText of an EditText as a string and not as an integer. Also how do you call countUp? You didn't write that in your code. Try my answer and tell me. :)

Comment: @HusseinElFeky Yes true I created my object in the wrong "space", and you had right with them being float instead of long. However it turned out that TimerTask is not really efficent if you want precise time on your events, so I changed to `Handler` class instead. I will however accept your answer :)

Comment: Thanks. :) if you can also vote my answer up, that would be great. I am not the one who down voted your answer in case you suspect me, I don't why that voter did that...

Comment: @HusseinElFeky done and done my friend. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your whole code with this one:

```
public class CountUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText upText;
    TimerTask tt;
    int counter = 0;

    //startTime and offsetTime must be long and not float.
    long startTime = 0;
    long offsetTime = 1000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Change this to your current layout.
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        upText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Up);

        tt = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                upText.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                counter++;
            }
        };
    }

    public void countUp(View view) {
        try {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, startTime, offsetTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```